# Removing Multi Ocurrences of a Word

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

How to remove the multiple occurrences of words in a `String`? The hard thing here is, I don't know which word it is. See below examples.

> This is how how I tried to split a paragraph into a sentence sentence  But, there is a problem  My paragraph `includes` dates dates dates dates like Jan 13, 2014 , words `includes` like U S and numbers

Here, some words have multiple occurrence. Words like `sentence`, `dates`, `includes` and `how` have occurred more than once. Note than this repeat may not occur near to each other, like `includes`. I want to remove these so it will be like below.

> This is how I tried to split a paragraph into a sentence  But, there is a problem  My paragraph includes dates like Jan 13, 2014 , words like U S and numbers

Note that removing multi occurrence does not mean removing all occurrences of the multi occurred word. It will simply keep a one copy and remove the rest.

Just like the above, there will be very big `String`s which I have no idea about which word has occurred more than once. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the text one word at a time and ignore the duplicates along the way.  Use a hashset to keep track of the duplicates.

Something like this...

```
String text = "This is how how I tried to split a paragraph into a sentence sentence But, there is a problem My paragraph includes dates dates dates dates like Jan 13, 2014 , words includes like U S and numbers"; 
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for(String s : text.split(" ")) {
    if (!set.contains(s)) {
        result.append(s);
        result.append(" ");
        set.add(s);
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

You'll have to touch it up a little to handle the punctuation properly, but that should get you started,.

Comment: @halfer Typo.  looks like the code snippet was right though

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
String rtsruoy = new StringBuilder(yourstr).reverse().toString();

String tluser = rtsruoy.replaceAll("(?s)(\\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}+\\b)(?=.*?\\1)", "");

String result =  new StringBuilder(tluser).reverse().toString();
```

Note: I have choosen to put 3 as minimum number of letter, you can choose what you want.

Comment: When i tested this (in java) it only seemed to remove consecutive duplicates, not ones scattered around the text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it seem that you should know the word to be replaces first (1)

Comment: @TedBigham: I have modified the code to deal with non contiguous words. (I haven't well read the question)

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess: I have edited my answer, It remove all duplicate words of 3 letters or more except the first word.

Comment: I don't think there was a requirement for 3 letters or more.  Why did you reverse the text?  That only seemed to affect whether the removed words were from the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

```
String original = "This is how how I tried to split a paragraph into a sentence sentence But, there is a problem My paragraph includes dates dates dates dates like Jan 13, 2014 , words includes like U S and numbers";
System.out.println(new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(original.split(" "))).toString().replace(", ", " "));
```

This would return:

> [This is how I tried to split a paragraph into sentence But, there
>   problem My includes dates like Jan 13, 2014 , words U S and numbers]